# Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Tags: powershell, ms-access-2016, aceoledb, access-database-engine

I have read myself in circles for days prior to posting this question, including all AI engines. Pardon this post again. I am looking for a fresh perspective.

I have this powershell script that works properly on my local computer. I have moved it to a server, installed Office 2016, ensured 2010 access database engine is installed (2007 was installed also as a desperate attempt). I have checked the registry and I see this

**Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**

This is the connection string

```
# Connection string for Access ACCDB database
$connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$DB_FILE;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

This is what the control panel shows

[image: Control Panel]

This is a windows 10 VM.
I have tried running with elevated privileges

The **ACEOLDDB.DLL** is located here in both office14 and office16 folders
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared**

The registry shows the ACE engine in these location

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\ACE**

Comment: You installed the 32bit version of the driver. The Process you spawn is probably 64bit. You can either create a 32bit Process or install the 64bit version of the driver. Note that you cannot have, in the same machine, both the 32 and 64bit version of the same Provider, but you can install a different version with a different bitness (e.g., the 32bit ACE.OLEDB.12 Provider and the 64bit ACE.OLEDB.16 Provider)

Comment: @Jimi -- this just saved what is left of my weekend. Thank you so much